# HTML, CSS - background image not changing

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCdRX.jpg

I was able to change the background color to Green with this: `style="background-color:green;"`
​

But I want to change it as background image with this:

`<body style="background-image: url("D:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\new\1image.jpg")";>`

(it doesn't work)
​

What's wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't escape `"` instead use `'` for the image `URL`:

```
<body style="background-image: url('D:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\new\1image.jpg');">
```

You can also use the relative path:

```
<body style="background-image: url('./1image.jpg');">
```

But, it's better to change it using `CSS` try to avoid inline styles as much as you can:

```
body {
  background-image: url("./1image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: thanks 'style="background-image: url('./1image.jpg');">' works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using nested quotes, so in your case it should rather be `<body style="background-image: url('D:\xampp\htdocs\youtube\new\1image.jpg')";>`.

The wrong syntax is - `"some text "some text" some text"`. The browser interprets it as - first string (quote 1 to quote 2) and string 2 (quote 3 to quote 4). Whereas what you expect is - parent string (quote 1 to quote 4) and nested string (quote 2 to quote 3). This is the correct syntax - `"some text 'some text' some text"`.